# Find array element with greatest or smallest sub-array element value

Tags: php, arrays

Element 1 of the following array represents the element with the greatest `x` value, and element 2 represents the element with the smallest `x` element.

Without looping over each array using PHP code, how can the index of the element with the greatest and smallest `x` be determined?

```
$array = [
    ['x'=>5,'y'=>3],
    ['x'=>9,'y'=>3],
    ['x'=>3,'y'=>3],
    ['x'=>7,'y'=>3]
];
```

Comment: You **have to loop** over each element how else do you know if there is a bigger value than you found?!

Comment: @Rizier123  What about AbraCadaver's solution?

Comment: Just because you don't see it in the code doesn't mean `array_column()` does not loop through the entire array, because it does. And you could use a simple foreach loop and then you would only loop over the array once and not like with `array_column()` twice.

Comment: To be more exact, if you use `array_column()` you not only have to loop over the array once to get the column, but also need to use `min()` and `max()`, which also needs to loop over the entire array. So in total you iterate over your array 3 times, just because you don't want to see "the loop" in your code. You could use a simple foreach loop and do everything in just one loop!

Comment: By using the restriction: `Without looping over each` - do you mean: 1) don't use a `foreach` loop statement 2) Use some instructions that don't compare adjacent entry values?  1) is satisfied using the 'array_*'  functions. 2) Is not possible with any computer that uses a standard CPU and  memory. To make it clear - all conventional computers always loop over the data.

Comment: @RyanVincent  I should have said "not looping over using PHP code".

Comment: Fist time a so little/tiny question gets that much comments ;-) Are we on Disqus? :-)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extract the `x` column and compute it:

```
$x = array_column($array, 'x');
$min = min($x);
$max = max($x);
```

Or, as *JustOnUnderMillions* points out:

```
list($min, $max) = [min($x=array_column($array, 'x')), max($x)];
```

To get the index of the array containing that value, just use `array_search()`.  It will return the first key if there are multiple identical values:

```
$x = array_column($array, 'x');
$min = array_search(min($x), $x, true);
$max = array_search(max($x), $x, true);
```

PHP >= 5.5.0 needed for `array_column()` or use the [PHP Implementation of array_column()](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php)

Comment: Please use `list()` to finally get a one-liner ;-)

Comment: An answer without `array_column()` isn't an answer right? :P Also you could include a simple foreach loop with which OP would only need to iterate the array once.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to get the index of the element (i.e. 1 for greatest and 2 for smallest), and not the value.

Comment: @Rizier123 Sure, `array_map` with `function($a)use(&$min,&max){}` would work also. Maybe the task was just a little bit to easy. :)

Comment: @user1032531 Opps, but nobody saw it like this! And for that you need another code snippet.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions  Including me!  I was the one applauding the loudest.  I should have said "array element INDEX".

Comment: @user1032531 Ok i try an answer for that.

Comment: @PaulCrovella:  Are you asking me or OP?

Comment: Yes, they are iterating, but are they not using some faster low-level language?  Not that the time maters, but more importantly, the code seems a little more concise.

Comment: @Paul Crovella Thing in the first time this `Without looping over each` means: I dont want too use a loop, is there a fancy function?