# Return array_column from an associative array when a search a min value

Tags: php, arrays, min

I have a loop to fill the $positions array like this:

```
array_push($positions, ["id" => $p->id, "distance"=> $distance, "date" => $p->date]);
```

Then i found the min key 'distance' like this:

```
$min = min(array_column($positions,'distance'));
```

Now i want to get the correspondent 'id' from the 'distance' founded.

How can i do this??

Comment: It would be easier to provide a functional answer you provided an actual array with values for `$positions`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39415397/2943403

Comment: @Bruno you should use Berto's technique _during_ the pushing loop so that you can reduce the number of loops executed in your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested:

```
$distances = array_column($positions,'distance', 'id');
$min = min($distances);
$id = array_search($min, $distances);
```

This gets the distances and creates a new array wth the `id` values as the keys. Then it gets the minimum value and uses it to search for the key that corresponds to it.

I am unsure what the result will be if you have multiple items with the same minimum value so you should test that out. But if you want all of the IDs with the min value you can use `array_keys()` with the optional `search_value` parameter instead.

```
$ids = array_keys($distances, $min);
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a custom algorithm (this has a computational complexity of `n`, where using your way is `2n`, so 2 times slower):

```
$positions= [...];
$min = $positions[0]['distance'];
$elements = [0];
foreach ($positions as $pos) {
   if ($pos["distance"] < $min) {
       $elements = [$pos];
       $min = $pos["distance"];
   } elseif ($pos["distance"] == $min) {
       $elements[] = $pos;
   }
}
```

But if you strictly need the `ids`, let me know and I will post the other algorithm.

Comment: This will probably be the best performer on the page because it only needs to iterate the incoming data once compared to:  `array_column()` (iteration), `min()` (iteration), then `array_search()` / `array_keys()` (iteration).  On the other hand, if code brevity is more important or if you find the declarative syntax of functional programming more favorable, use John's suggestion.

Comment: Please not use `else if` (two words) in PHP -- it is a violation of PSR guidelines because it is rendered as an equivalent of } else { if (...) {}}` but is missing the recommended curly brace between the two control structures.  https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/

Comment: @mickmackusa wow, every day something new, thanks, edited

Answer (score 0):

You could also index by the `id`, sort ascending and get the first key:

```
$distances = array_column($positions, 'distance', 'id');
asort($distances);
$id = key($distances);
```